# Symfony3: How to translate FormErrors added in eventListeners?

Tags: forms, symfony, translation, symfony-3.4

Let say I have this form:

```
//...
class BananaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('flavor');
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            if ($form->get('flavor')->getData() === null) {
                $form->addError(new FormError('form.error.flavor_missing'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even though the message **form.error.flavor_missing** is defined both in messages.yml and validators.yml, it's not displayed.

Any idea how to translate it? I hope I won't have to inject the `translator` service in every form using this kind of code in order to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

why not use [Validation Constraints](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/constraints.html)

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

// ...

class BananaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('flavor', YourType::class, array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new Assert\NotNull(), // or any other
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

You can use a custom message

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('flavor', YourType::class, array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new Assert\NotNull(array(
                    'message' => 'form.error.flavor_missing'
                )),
            ),
        ));
    }
```

Comment: because in my real app, the condition making me rise the error is much more complex and I need to do it in an eventListener. thanks anyway.

Comment: @Roubi You can create  a custom validator https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator

Comment: @IwanWijaya Yes, but there are still things that you can't do with a validator. And it would be easier to inject the translator in the form in that case

Comment: @Roubi You can inject a service into your validator class.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your dev environment, you should see the missing string. Taking a look at them, you should see the domain and the expected messages file.

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't appear in the missing strings list.

Comment: if you use the 'flavour' field of an specific entity across many forms, you can set a custom assert in the entity, unless the constraint requires data out of the current row.